# Seeing the memory usage of Emscripten-compiled JS memory arrays

Tags: emscripten

In Empscripten-compiled JS, is there some API I can call that tells the amount of space in the memory arrays that has been used up and the amount still available, such that I could add live instrumentation for this metric in a production application?

I mean "memory arrays" as in:

```
"Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X with X higher than the current value 402653184, (2) compile with -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 which adjusts the size at runtime but prevents some optimizations, (3) set Module.TOTAL_MEMORY to a higher value before the program runs, or if you want malloc to return NULL (0) instead of this abort, compile with -s ABORTING_MALLOC=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `--memoryprofiler` and tune it a bit to reach your goal.

But better solution is to write your own method - here is description what is needed https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/8082#issuecomment-483963811

If you are not interested in above solution - just use `-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1` as recommended in error you get (or just prealloc maximum possible amount i.e. for Chrome 64-bit 4GB, for Chrome 32-bit 512 MB).